# Can I watch full HD Videos on a supported TV from a laptop without a full HD display?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv, high-definition

I have a notebook with 1366 × 768 screen resolution but with an HDMI out port, that can be connected to my TV. My TV has an HDMI input port and supports a screen resolution of 1920 × 1080. Is it possible to watch Full HD movies stored on my notebook, on my TV screen using an HDMI cable, which obviously isn't possible on my notebook screen?

Additional details: I have an NVIDIA GT-610M - 1 GB GPU, and also an integrated Intel graphics card.

Comment: You should be able to go into the display properties area in your notebook. The tv should show up as a monitor selection. click the picture and tell it to change resolution to what your tv is capable. Take note your video card may not be able to produce the 1920X1080 resolution.

Comment: Thanks, where may I check how much (or max) resolution my graphics card is capable to handle. Especially, since I also have another old notebook with an Intel Graphics 3000 alone.

Comment: the little resolution slider should tell you the max capable when you click on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notebook screen resolution will not have anything to do with the graphics provided by your HDMI output. According to the specs I found about your graphics card; it is able to decode two simultaneous streams of 1080p (I assume that is what you mean by 'Full HD') quality video. Which would mean your graphics processor is not only capable of 1080p quality output, it could handle Picture-in-Picture at 1080p quality.

> Is it possible to watch Full HD movies stored on my notebook, on my TV screen using an HDMI cable, which obviously isn't possible on my notebook screen?

Yes, assuming your TV supports it. 1920x1080 is only the resolution, 'Full HD' typically refers to 1080p support.

Comment: Thanks! What then is the difference between 1920 × 1080 resolution and 1080p video? How do I check if my TV supports 'Full HD'?

Comment: 1080p is the shorthand identification for a set of HDTV video modes which are characterised by 1,080 lines of vertical resolution (1,080 horizontal scan lines) and progressive scan (meaning the image is not interlaced, unlike the 1080i display standard).

Comment: 1920 is horizontal resolution number and 1080 is vertical. you laptop lcd is only capable of 720p resolution, which is still HD but not full HD

Comment: 1920x1080 is the number of columns and rows of pixels. 1080p and 1080i will have the same amount of pixels. The 'p' stands for progressive scan. This means that the odd and even lines of pixels are all updated at your refresh rate. The 'i' stands for interlace scan which means the odd and even rows alternate updating at your refresh rate. Example: Refresh rate = 120hz, in 1080p the whole screen would be updated at 120hz whereas, it would only be updated at 60hz in 1080i mode.

Comment: The easiest way to see if you TV supports 1080p is to check the specs (Bing it if you threw the manual and box away).

Answer (score 1):

Your computer will treat the TV as an external monitor.  As your video card also supports this resolution, you should have no problem using your TV to watch Full HD video.

Comment: @xibalban: Click on the check below the voting controls for the answer that best solves your problem, so that we know that your problem is solved.